# Sencha store many to one relationship generation based on ids

Tags: extjs, extjs6, many-to-one, relational

While trying to work out many to one relationships I seem to be unable to let sencha generate them automatically based on given ids.

What I have are two models and two stores (in 4 files):

Model `Customer`:

```
Ext.define('Customer', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        unique: true,
    }, {
        name: 'name',
    }]
});
```

Store customer:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Customer', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'Customer',
    alias: 'store.customer',
    autoLoad: true,

    model: 'Customer',

    data: {
        items: [
            {id: 1, name: 'paul'},
            {id: 3, name: 'W'}
        ]
    },

    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items'
        }
    }
});
```

model ticket:

```
Ext.define('Ticket', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        unique: true,
    }, {
        name: 'title'
    }, {
        name: 'customerId',
        reference: {
            type: 'Customer',
            inverse: 'tickets',
            getterName: 'getCustomer',
            setterName: 'setCustomer',
        }
    }]
});
```

And finally the tickestore:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Ticket', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'Ticket',
    alias: 'store.ticket',
    autoLoad: true,

    model: 'Ticket',

    data: {
        items: [{id: 1000, title: 'blah', customerId: 1}]
    },

    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items'
        }
    }

});
```

now this should be fairly straightforward: I have a single customer which "has a" single ticket. The reason I split these stores apart instead of defining everything in the customer store is because later I wish to load & handle those two things separately.

Now when I run this, and test this setup in some controller I find an astonishing result:

```
const thestore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Customer');
const ticketstore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Ticket');
debugger;

const customer = thestore.findRecord('id', 1);
const ticket = ticketstore.findRecord('id', 1000);

const t = customer.tickets();
const c = ticket.getCustomer();
const basename = customer.get('name');
const customername = c.get('name');
console.dir(basename);
console.dir(customername);
```

I notice that "basename" and "customername" are inequeal, actually the customername is "blank": which indicates that the reference isn't working at all. Using a debugger shows indeed that there are now two different models with id "1", and the ticket has created its own customer (instead of hooking itself up to the customer).

How can I define (when returning data for the ticketstore) that a ticket belongs to a customer?

Answer (score 0):

It should be using the hasmany config inside your customer model with type as Ticket.

```
hasMany: [
    {
        name: 'Ticket',
        model: 'Ticket'
    },
]
```

It automatically associates the tickets to the customer but you must have a foreign key in the customer table to the ticket table. I hope it will help.